# OAuth Issue for Pinger

Tags: php, curl, oauth

So here is what I currently have, I'm trying to make a script with PHP/cURL that will login to the Pinger TextFree Web service.

I have no idea what I'm missing, I'm not seeing the HTTP transaction for the OAuth. I've read a bit about it but I"m still lost.

Any suggestions?

```
function sendRequest($url, $postorget, $fields = array(), $proxy)
{

$cookie_file = "cookies.txt";

//Initiate connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); // set url
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return the transfer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // allow https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'); // random agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // automatically follow Location: headers (ie redirects)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // auto set the referer in the event of a redirect
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5); // ibm likes to redirect a lot, make sure we dont get stuck in a loop
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file); // file to save cookies in
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file); // file to read cookies from
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 40); //timeout time for curl

//Check to see if a proxy is being used
if(isset($proxy)){
    //Tell cURL you're using a proxy
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    //Set the proxy
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
}

//Check if request is POST or GET
if ($postorget == "post" OR $postorget == "POST")
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // use POST
    if (is_array($fields)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields)); // key => name gets turned into &key=name
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); // &key=name passed in
    }
} else { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false); // use GET
}

$content = curl_exec($ch); // return html content
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); // return transfer info
$error = curl_error($ch);  // return any errors

curl_close($ch);

$request = array('content' => $content,
         'error' => $error,
     'info' => $info);

return $request;            
}
    //Login details
$username = "usernaem";
$password = "password";

//GET the initial login page
$initFields = "";
$initOutput = sendRequest("http://www.pinger.com/tfw/?t=1360619019053", "GET", $initFields);

echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='400'>";
print_r($initOutput);
echo "</textarea>";

//Login to pinger
$loginFields = "{\"username\":\"".$username."\",\"password\":\"".$password."\",\"clientId\":\"textfree-in-flash-web-free-1360619009-8CA1C5C1-38ED-2E31-3248-CB367450A20F\"}";
$loginOutput = sendRequest("https://api.pinger.com/1.0/web/login", "POST", $loginFields);

echo "<textarea cols='100' rows='400'>";
print_r($loginOutput);
echo "</textarea>";
```

Answer (score -2):

We noticed this section in script with PHP/cURL where the user names are mentioned.

Please check this section of the code:

```
    //Login details
```

$username = "usernaem";
$password = "password";

You will notice that the section that specifies **username** is misspelled

> usernaem

Please try correcting this error and this should fix your issue.